# How can I remove this flapper alternative?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I had good luck in the past using [this product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BlueSource-HydroStop-Flapperless-Flush-and-Repair-FLT231/203228546#.UZ-62dLVDjU) to replace a leaky flapper valve.

[image: flapperless repair kit]

However, this new  toilet does not have a flapper hinge on the  base of the flush valve.  Instead, there is a hinged piece of plastic that looks like two cylinders attached to each other at right angles.  The bottom flush valve ring has a piece going straight up that this "flapper" attaches to, and I have no idea how to take it off so that I can just replace that assembly with this kit I've purchased.

[image: flapper alternative]
[image: flapper alternative open]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your flush valve looks like, when it's not in your toilet.

[image]

This bit should be flexible enough, to allow you to bend it out of the way on both sides.

[image]

The pins holding the actuating unit in place should slip out of the holes, and the whole piece can be removed. The best method to remove the actuating unit, is to gently pry the bracket with a screw driver on one side, then twist the actuating unit so that the pin on that side pops free.  Once one pin is out, it should be easy to get the other side out.

Comment: Indeed, it took quite a bit of force on those side hole brackets to get the flapper to pop out.